# Sharepoint StateMachine : Handling multiple responses to multiple created tasks

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, state-machine

I created a StateMachine workflow for sharepoint and at one state, I create multiple tasks    using a replicator. The number of tasks created is variable.

I need to handle the OnTaskChanged event for all the tasks I created which seems impossible as one event handler can only be associated with one task.

I can use a restrictive number of tasks which can be created and handled by a specific number of handlers but I am considering that as a last resort or create a sequential workflow as a last resort.

Please do let me know if this is even supported or if there are any workarounds.

Reference Link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/a174ac5f-03ed-4e27-998b-bbdb7d01d09b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work for the reasons you laid out. The workaround is to restructure your state machine workflow as a sequential workflow (which may not be possible) or to switch to item event receivers (which may not work for you). I've actually blogged about this topic: [Workflow Nuttiness vol. 1](http://www.pseale.com/blog/SharePointWorkflowNuttinessVolume1.aspx)

Hilariously, I just checked the MSDN forums link you provided, and sure enough, I'm in that thread, asking "so, uh, I guess we all rewrite to sequential workflows?" And there's no better answer in that thread either :)